# SQL Server Table Dump - Not All Columns

Tags: sql-server, data-dump, data-export

I'm trying to do an SQL Server dump of a couple of tables in a database (Microsoft SQL Server). We don't have write access to the DB, so we can't do what I was originally thinking (create temp db, copy tables (minus the columns we don't want into the temp db, and then dump that db). I really can't figure out a way to do this.

A csv export doesn't work (it's almost impossible to put the data in the correct fields b/c of newlines).

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

[Bulk Copy is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) your friend

Answer (score 1):

Either bulk copy, or create a DTS (or SSIS) package that exports to a MS Access database.  In access, all the line breaks will be preserved within their corresponding text fields.

Comment: DTS?  I've never heard of that before

Comment: DTS = Data Transformation Services, in SQL Server 2005 and up SSIS = SQL Server Integration Services. Your best friend to load in or dump out large amounts of data!